# Why does Python quit when I call root = Tk()?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, anaconda, spyder

I created a new Python environment for Anaconda/Spyder on my Mac (downgrading from 3.7 to 3.6 so I could use Keras), and now Tkinter no longer works. "root = Tk()" makes Python quit, with an Apple error message that says "python quit unexpectedly." Why?

That line still works in IDLE, which uses a different installation of Python 3.6.

Comment: The Python installation may be broken when you downgrade it.  Uninstall it and install 3.6 again.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why, but that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acw1668's comment solved it: "The Python installation may be broken when you downgrade it. Uninstall it and install 3.6 again."